# copy canvas to another canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i use this function for copy old canvas to new canvas

```
function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {

        //create a new canvas
        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

        //set dimensions
        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

        //apply the old canvas to the new one
        context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);

        //return the new canvas
        return newCanvas;
    }
```

and i use this function like this

```
            var oldCanvas = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child canvas')

            $("div.previewImg").append(cloneCanvas(oldCanvas))
```

but i get this error :(

```
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided
```

please help me , how i can solve this error

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to be sure you get one element and not an array use:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child canvas').first();
```

Second:

To copy the image data from an array use [toDataUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975241(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
canvasDataImg = oldCanvasContext.toDataURL("image/png");
```

And then draw to the new canvas.

Comment: canvasDataImg = oldCanvasContext.toDataURL("image/png"); May fail if there is any image with cross domain. It is best to use context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldCanvas = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child canvas')[0];
if(oldCanvas){ //Check if the element is present
    $("div.previewImg").append(cloneCanvas(oldCanvas))
}
```